# Incompatibilidade Navegador Edge UpdatePanel

Tags: html, html5, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um UpdatePanel, que funciona perfeitamente, nos navegadores chrome e no firefox, ele não atualiza a página, quando altero algo na combobox, porém no navegador EDGE ela atualiza, já tentei colocando vários códigos de modo de compatibilidade mais nenhum funciona corretamente no EDGE, preciso que o updatepanel funcione, o erro não está no código, pois conforme informei em outros navegadores funciona conforme o esperado. 
Último código que coloquei, porém também sem sucesso:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer para que funcione corretamente no EDGE ?

Comment: No HTML5 vc não precisa declarar isso **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"** apesar de não saber se vai resolver o problema...

Comment: Tirei, porém não resolveu o problema.

Comment: Se tiver algum `<a href="#'...></a>` no seu JS vc pode colocar um `Event.preventDefault()`para ver se resolve... https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: O código todo está funcionando nos navegadores como Chrome e no Firefox, só no edge que o updatepanel não funciona.